# what is the flask equivalent of SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.rfile.read()?

Tags: python, http, flask, esp-idf, basehttprequesthandler

I'm running the esp-adf pipeline_raw_http example and I'm trying to reimplement the server.py in flask.
the esp board sends out the wav audio stream using http stream with the following code:

```
esp_err_t _http_stream_event_handle(http_stream_event_msg_t *msg)
{
    esp_http_client_handle_t http = (esp_http_client_handle_t)msg->http_client;
    char len_buf[16];
    static int total_write = 0;

    if (msg->event_id == HTTP_STREAM_PRE_REQUEST)
    {
        // set header
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "[ + ] HTTP client HTTP_STREAM_PRE_REQUEST, lenght=%d", msg->buffer_len);
        esp_http_client_set_method(http, HTTP_METHOD_POST);
        char dat[10] = {0};
        snprintf(dat, sizeof(dat), "%d", EXAMPLE_AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE);
        esp_http_client_set_header(http, "x-audio-sample-rates", dat);
        memset(dat, 0, sizeof(dat));
        snprintf(dat, sizeof(dat), "%d", EXAMPLE_AUDIO_BITS);
        esp_http_client_set_header(http, "x-audio-bits", dat);
        memset(dat, 0, sizeof(dat));
        snprintf(dat, sizeof(dat), "%d", EXAMPLE_AUDIO_CHANNELS);
        esp_http_client_set_header(http, "x-audio-channel", dat);
        total_write = 0;
        return ESP_OK;
    }

    if (msg->event_id == HTTP_STREAM_ON_REQUEST)
    {
        // write data
        int wlen = sprintf(len_buf, "%x\r\n", msg->buffer_len);
        if (esp_http_client_write(http, len_buf, wlen) <= 0)
        {
            return ESP_FAIL;
        }
        if (esp_http_client_write(http, msg->buffer, msg->buffer_len) <= 0)
        {
            return ESP_FAIL;
        }
        if (esp_http_client_write(http, "\r\n", 2) <= 0)
        {
            return ESP_FAIL;
        }
        total_write += msg->buffer_len;
        printf("\033[A\33[2K\rTotal bytes written: %d\n", total_write);
        return msg->buffer_len;
    }

    if (msg->event_id == HTTP_STREAM_POST_REQUEST)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "[ + ] HTTP client HTTP_STREAM_POST_REQUEST, write end chunked marker");
        if (esp_http_client_write(http, "0\r\n\r\n", 5) <= 0)
        {
            return ESP_FAIL;
        }
        return ESP_OK;
    }

    if (msg->event_id == HTTP_STREAM_FINISH_REQUEST)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "[ + ] HTTP client HTTP_STREAM_FINISH_REQUEST");
        char *buf = calloc(1, 64);
        assert(buf);
        int read_len = esp_http_client_read(http, buf, 64);
        if (read_len <= 0)
        {
            free(buf);
            return ESP_FAIL;
        }
        buf[read_len] = 0;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Got HTTP Response = %s", (char *)buf);
        free(buf);
        return ESP_OK;
    }
    return ESP_OK;
}
```

the default server.py receives the stream with:

```
class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self, length):
        self.send_response(200)
        if length > 0:
            self.send_header('Content-length', str(length))
        self.end_headers()

    def _get_chunk_size(self):
        data = self.rfile.read(2)
        while data[-2:] != b"\r\n":
            data += self.rfile.read(1)
        return int(data[:-2], 16)

    def _get_chunk_data(self, chunk_size):
        data = self.rfile.read(chunk_size)
        self.rfile.read(2)
        return data

    def _write_wav(self, data, rates, bits, ch):
        t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        time = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
        filename = str.format('{}_{}_{}_{}.wav', time, rates, bits, ch)

        wavfile = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
        wavfile.setparams((ch, int(bits/8), rates, 0, 'NONE', 'NONE'))
        wavfile.writeframesraw(bytearray(data))
        wavfile.close()
        return filename

    def do_POST(self):
        urlparts = parse.urlparse(self.path)
        request_file_path = urlparts.path.strip('/')
        total_bytes = 0
        sample_rates = 0
        bits = 0
        channel = 0
        print("Do Post......")
        if (request_file_path == 'upload'
            and self.headers.get('Transfer-Encoding', '').lower() == 'chunked'):
            data = []
            sample_rates = self.headers.get('x-audio-sample-rates', '').lower()
            bits = self.headers.get('x-audio-bits', '').lower()
            channel = self.headers.get('x-audio-channel', '').lower()
            sample_rates = self.headers.get('x-audio-sample-rates', '').lower()

            print("Audio information, sample rates: {}, bits: {}, channel(s): {}".format(sample_rates, bits, channel))
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500752/how-can-i-read-exactly-one-response-chunk-with-pythons-http-client
            while True:
                chunk_size = self._get_chunk_size()
                total_bytes += chunk_size
                print("Total bytes received: {}".format(total_bytes))
                sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
                if (chunk_size == 0):
                    break
                else:
                    chunk_data = self._get_chunk_data(chunk_size)
                    data += chunk_data

            filename = self._write_wav(data, int(sample_rates), int(bits), int(channel))
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html;charset=utf-8")
            self.send_header("Content-Length", str(total_bytes))
            self.end_headers()
            body = 'File {} was written, size {}'.format(filename, total_bytes)
            self.wfile.write(body.encode('utf-8'))
```

I searched online but I can't find the flask equivalent of the rfile.read() in the _get_chunk_size(self): function, I tried with the request.stream.read() and the request.input_stream.read(), but the encoding wasn't right, the output of rfile.read(2) is b'10' and the datatype is bytes, when the function returns the data will become b'1000\r\n'. however with the request.stream.read(2) the output is "b'\x1b\x00'", if I change the read(2) to read(100), the output is "b'\xdf\x00\xde\x00\xc2\x00\xe7\x00\xdf\x00\xb5\x00\xd6\x00\xc5\x00\xe1\x00\x99\x00\xcc\x00\xb3\x00\xa9\x00\x8b\x00\xa8\x00\x88\x00\xa3\x00\x95\x00\x80\x00\x80\x00\x8b\x00h\x00\xa4\x00F\x00}\x00L\x00\x85\x00B\x00}\x00P\x00\x89\x00I\x00`\x00i\x00\xa5\x00k\x00\xb4\x00u\x00\xb7\x00p\x00\xb3\x00t\x00\xcf\x00v\x00\xf9\x00\x9c\x00\xea\x00w\x00\xec\x00u\x00'". am I reading the wrong thing here?

Comment: That looks like 16-bit PCM audio data to me.  What were you expecting?

Comment: thank you @TimRoberts, the server.py has two methods that read from the rfile, _get_chunk_size and _get_chunk_data, the _get_chunk_size should read about only 6 characters and return 4096, the _get_chunk_data should read for 4096 characters of audio data, and this data stream is indeed in 16 bit format. however it appears that when I'm using flask request.stream.read(), a portion of data at the head is skipped, so the read chunck size returns audio data directly.

Comment: Have you tried `request.get_data()` to get the whole thing as one unit?  Although `request.stream.read()` should work.  It's interesting that you showed us code that worked, but not the code you need help with.